# UbuntuでArduino IDEが文字化けする

Tags: linux, 文字化け, arduino, ubuntu

Ubuntu14.04にて[このページ](http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Ubuntu)を参考に以下のコマンドでArduino IDEをインストールしましたが、日本語がうまく表示されないようです。

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core`

文字化けを解消する方法を教えていただきたいです。

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: テキスト入力部分に日本語を入力した場合も文字化けしますか？

Comment: @heliac2001 インストールした時点ではテキスト入力部分も文字化けしていましたが、`~/.arduino/preferences.txt`の`editor.font`を日本語フォントに書き換えたところ、テキスト入力部分のみ文字化けが解消しました。

Comment: @h2so5 自己解決した場合には、解決策を回答として投稿して、チェックマークをつけて頂けると、他の方の参考になると思います。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arduino はメニュー部分とテキスト入力部分とでは別のフォント設定を行っている様です。以下にメニューフォントの文字化けを解消する方法(実際にはメニューフォントの切り替え)が記載されています。

[How to change Arduino IDE menu font size?](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=142277.0)

具体的には以下の2通りの方法が記載されていました。

- /usr/bin/arduino(シェルスクリプト)の最後の行を変更
- GTK のフォントエントリを設定

/usr/bin/arduino を変更したところ、私の環境(Ubuntu 14.04)でもメニューフォントが正常化(？)しました。